# Get the email subject line as a variable in VBA while sending the email

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I am writing code to get the subject line of an email as it's sent but for some reason I am not getting anything in the variable.

Below is the code I have used:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim yPrompt As String
    Dim xOkOrCancel As Integer
    Dim abc As Outlook.MailItem

    On Error Resume Next
    yPrompt = abc.Subject
    xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(yPrompt, vbOKCancel)
    If xOkOrCancel <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Could someone please help me as I'm new to VBA and not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: What mail? If you have three mail accounts with 1,000 mail items in each, how does this code select a single mail item? As already mentioned, the first thing you need to do is remove `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Pretty sure `Application_ItemSend()` is a method that is triggered by the application sending an email as long as it is in a Class Module with the application defined before hand.

Comment: Hey Thanks Nick and Taazar it worked with the changes suggested by Alex Thanks for the response.

Comment: Oh so _thats_ how it picks a mail. I humbly retract my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `resume next` line - having it there is hiding useful error information that would help you diagnose the problem.

You declare `abc` then attempt to read it's `.Subject` - this is both a runtime error (hidden by `resume next` as above) and a logical error because you have not assigned it to anything.

The event proc is providing you with the message in `Item` so you just can simply  use `Item.Subject`.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for the answer.  It worked Below is the code I changed as suggested --

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim yPrompt As String
Dim xOkOrCancel As Integer
'Dim abc As Outlook.MailItem

'On Error Resume Next
yPrompt = Item.Subject
xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(yPrompt, vbOKCancel)
If xOkOrCancel <> vbOK Then
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Now I want To use the same code on the click of the command button in one for can you please guide me for the same.